# Undefined index: sessionName

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

Hello I have created a login page which is

```html
 <form method="POST" action="log.php">

<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"
 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; border: 0px; text-align: left; margin-top: 5px; background-color: transparent;"
 width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td style="border: 0px; width: 20%; background-color: transparent;">
    Username:</td>
   <td style="border: 0px; width: 30%; background-color: transparent;">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"
    autocomplete="off" required="">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>

<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0"
 style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; border: 0px; text-align: left; margin-top: 5px; background-color: transparent;"
 width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td style="border: 0px; width: 20%; background-color: transparent;">
    Password:</td>
   <td style="border: 0px; width: 30%; background-color: transparent;">
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control"
    autocomplete="off" required>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
</div>


<div class="spacer-20"></div>

</div>
<!-- Social Signup -->
<div class="social-signup">
 <span class="or-break"></span>
 <center>
 <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login
 </button>
 No account? <a href="joinus.php"> Sign up</a>

</form>
```

and the login Processor is as follows

```html
<?php
// Login Controller
// require('config/config.php');
include './config/config.php';
$userName = $passWord = $name = "";

if (isset ( $_POST ['login'] )) {
 $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con, $_POST ['email'] );
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con, $_POST ['pass'] );
 $pass = md5 ( $password );
 // Block handles Doctor Login using the email
 $get_doc = "SELECT * FROM doctor_registration WHERE email='$userName' AND password='$pass'";
 $run_doc = mysqli_query ( $con, $get_doc );
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_array ( $run_doc );
 $docId = $rows ['doc_id'];
 $docEmail = $rows ['email'];
 $name = $rows ['first_name'] . " " . $rows ['last_name'];
 
 if ($userName == $docEmail) {
  $_SESSION ['sessionName'] = $name;
  $_SESSION ['sessionId'] = $docId;
  echo "<script>window.open('doctor_dashboard.php','_self')</script>";
 } else {
  // Block handles user Login using the username
  $get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userName' AND password='$pass'";
  $run_user = mysqli_query ( $con, $get_user );
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_array ( $run_user );
  $userId = $rows ['user_id'];
  $uname = $rows ['username'];
  if ($userName == $uname) {
   $_SESSION ['sessionName'] = $uname;
   $_SESSION ['sessionId'] = $userId;
   echo "<script>window.open('user_dashboard.php','_self')</script>";
  } else {
   echo "<script>alert('Passowrd or username is not correct!')</script>";
  }
 }
}
?>
```

and for the dashboard the processor checks the email or username and redirects to one of the dashboard.

i have two dashboards which have the code bellow for starting and storing a session

```html
<?php
 session_start ();
 include './config/config.php';
 include './updateFunction.php';
 include './InsertFunction.php';
 
 if (isset ( $_SESSION ['sessionName'] ) && ($_SESSION ['sessionId'])) {
  header ( "location:index.php" );
 }
?>
```

and each time i try to login in both dashboards i get the error:

> Undefined index: sessionName

Comment: on the page you are expecting the global session variable, just put a print_r ( $_SESSION ); after the session start to see if the session is even being set... also i don't see where you are starting the session on the "processing page'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION['sessionName'] = $name`

in the login processor.

So preferably you should use `session_start()` at the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0):

Put `session_start();` in your config.php after `<?php`

then call config.php on every page on after `<?php`

you are getting session error because you haven't use `session_start();` in your file

Comment: @FRANKOJAMBO dont add space or tag before  session_start ();